# If $P$ a probability of a sentence to be true, then $\{P(\phi | T_i)\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a martingale over constructed theories $T_i$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, logic

I am reading Section 2.1 of [Definability of Truth in Probabilistic Logic](http://intelligence.org/files/DefinabilityTruthDraft.pdf).

For a language $L$, fix a probability distribution $P:L \to [0,1]$. Enumerate sentences $\phi_1, \phi_2, \ldots$ of a language $L$, let the first $L$-theory be $T_0:=\emptyset$. Let $\phi_j$ be the first sentence independent of a theory $T_i$. Then let $T_{i+1}:=T_i \cup \{\phi_j\}$ with the probability $P(\phi_j\mid T_i)$ and $T_{i+1}:=T_i \cup \{\neg \phi_j\}$ with the probability $P(\neg \phi_j\mid T_i)$ where $P(\phi_j\mid T_i) = P(\phi_j \land T_i) / P(T_i)$.

Further suppose that the following holds

$$P(\phi \mid  T_i) = P(\phi \mid  T_i \land \phi_j)P(\phi_j \mid  T_i)+P(\phi \mid  T_i \land \neg \phi_j)P(\neg \phi_j \mid  T_i).$$

Show that the sequence $\{P(\phi | T_i)\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a martingale.

My problem is that I do not know probability theory and when looking at the definition of a martingale at Wikipedia, it implies that if a sequence $\{X_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ of random variables is a discrete-time martingale, then $E(X_1 | X_0)=X_0$. But I do not even know how to show that $E(P(\phi \mid \phi_j) \mid P(\phi))=P(\phi)$.

Comment: I think, $P$ is defined on sentences of $L$ rather than just on $L$. Also, it seems that $P(\phi|T_i)$ is a deterministic value according to the footnote 1, hence it is a martingale iff it is a constant sequence

Comment: @Ilya Yes, the sequence has deterministic values. What is a constant sequence? The sequence above does not have all the values the same for every $i \in \mathbb{N}$ in general. Yes, $P$ is defined on the sentences, that is the abuse of notation.

Comment: A (real-valued) martingale is a sequence of random variables $X_i$ satisfying among other things $\mathsf E [X_{i+1}|X_0,\dots,X_1] = X_i$. In particular, $\mathsf EX_i = \mu$ does not depend on $i$. If $X_i$ is deterministic then $\mathsf EX_i = X_i$, so that a sequence of deterministic values is a martingale iff $X_i = \mu$ for all $i$.

Comment: @Ilya Could they use a different definition of a martingale? Let $\phi$ be a non-trivial sentence, i.e. that is not true and not false. Then let $T_1=\{\phi\}$. Then $X_0=P(\phi)\neq 1$, but $X_1=P(\phi|\{\phi\})=1$. As $X_0 \neq X_1$, this sequence extensible to a martingale cannot be constant.

Comment: If you make the calculations, you can verify that $P(\phi \mid  T_i) = P(\phi \land T_i)/P(T_i)$. When i "increases" you will "throw into" $T_i$ progressively all the formulae; thus, at a certain stage $k$, $\phi$ or $\lnot \phi$ will "come in". If $\lnot \phi$ comes in then, for $j >k$, $\phi \land T_j$ includes a contradiction and thus, by Ax.3 its probability is $0$. Otherwise, $\phi$ "comes in and thus $P(\phi \land T_j) = P(T_j)$, i.e. $P(\phi \land T_i)/P(T_i)=1$.

Comment: In the proof of Theorem 1 they define $T_0$ as the emptyset $T_0=\emptyset$ and then they say (several lines later) that $\mathbb P(T_0)=1$. I find this confusing.

Comment: @Stef See Mauro's reply that clarifies in the end why $\emptyset$ is treated as a tautology.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for your answer, sorry I did not reply to your comment earlier, I needed to understand more, as given in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaim* : I'm not a specialist of probability; thus, this is only an **HINT**.

See John Walsh, [Notes on Elementary Martingale Theory](https://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Ewalsh/marts.pdf) :

> *Conditional probability of $B$ given $A$* : $P(B | A) = P(A \cap B) /P(A)$
>
> *Conditional expectation of $X$ given $A$* : If $B$ is an event then, $I_B$ is a random variable with $P(I_B = 1 | A) = P(B | A)$, and $P(I_B = 0 | A) = 1 − P(B | A)$ so that :
>
> > $P(B | A) = E(I_B | A)$.
>
> **Definition 2.1** A *filtration* on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ is a sequence $\{ \mathcal F_n : n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots \}$ of sub-sigma fields of $\mathcal F$ such that for all $n, \mathcal F_n \subset \mathcal F_{n+1}$.

In our case, the *filtration* is the sequence of $\mathcal L$-*theories* $T_i$ : it is true that $T_i \subset T_{i+1}$.

> **Definition 2.2** A *stochastic process* is a collection of random variables defined on the same probability space.

In our case, the formula $\varphi$ is the stochastic process.

> **Definition 2.3** A stochastic process $X = \{ X_n, n = 0, 1, 2,\ldots \}$, is *adapted* to the filtration $(\mathcal F_n)$ if for all $n, X_n$ is $\mathcal F_n$-measurable.
>
> **Definition 2.4** A process $X = \{ X_n, \mathcal F_n, n = 0, 1, 2,\ldots \}$, is a *martingale* if for each $n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$,
>
> (i) $\{ \mathcal F_n, n = 0, 1, 2 \ldots \}$ is a filtration and $X$ is adapted to $(\mathcal F_n)$;
>
> (ii) for each $n, X_n$ is integrable;
>
> (iii) for each $n, E(X_{n+1} | \mathcal F_n) = X_n$.

*Conditions (i) and (ii) are not clear to me ...*

We have to check condition (iii), that in our case seems to be :

> $P(\varphi|T_i)=P(\varphi)$.

---

Consider the comment below the formula of page 3 :

> By axiom 3, $P(T_0) = 1$ [recall that $T_0 = \emptyset$], so $P(\varphi | T_0) = P(\varphi)$.

Consider now $i=0$; by construction, $T_{i+1} = T_1$ i.e.$= \emptyset \cup \{ \varphi_1$ } or $= \emptyset \cup \{ \lnot \varphi_1 \}$.

Thus, with $P(\varphi|T_i)=P(\varphi \land T_i)/P(T_i)$, **due to the fact that we have only two possibility for building $T_1$ : add to $T_0=\emptyset$ either $\varphi_1$ or $\lnot \varphi_1$**  we have that [to be verified] :

> $P(\varphi|T_1) = P(\varphi|\varphi_1)P(\varphi_1|T_0) + P(\varphi|\lnot \varphi_1)P(\lnot \varphi_1|T_0)$

i.e.

> $=P(\varphi_1)/P(T_0) \times P(\varphi \land \varphi_1)/P(\varphi_1) + P(\lnot \varphi_1)/P(T_0) \times P(\varphi \land \lnot \varphi_1)/P(\lnot \varphi_1)$

and simplifying and recalling that $P(T_0)=P(\emptyset)=1$ :

> $=P(\varphi \land \varphi_1) + P(\varphi \land \lnot \varphi_1) = P(\varphi)$

by axiom 1.

Iterating this process [see formula page 3], we have that $P(\varphi|T_i)=P(\varphi)$, for all $i$.

---

Now, applying Ilya's comment above :

> > $P(\varphi|T_i)$ is a deterministic value, hence it is a martingale iff it is a constant sequence

we have that it is a constant sequence; thus, it is a martingale.

---

---

*Note*

The fact that $P(\emptyset)=1$ means that they treat $\emptyset$ as a *tautology*.

This fact is consistent with the usual definition of *tautology* as a formula that is *tautologically implied* by the empty set of premises :

> $\tau$ is a *tautology* **iff** $\emptyset \vDash \tau$.

The reason for it is [see Enderton, page 23] :

> [Consider $\Sigma \vDash \tau$ and] take the special case in which $\Sigma$ is the empty set $\emptyset$. Observe that it is vacuously true that any truth assignment satisfies every member of $\emptyset$. (How could this fail? Only if there was some unsatisfied member of $\emptyset$, which is absurd.)
>
> Hence we are left with: $\emptyset \vDash \tau$ iff every truth assignment (for the sentence symbols in $\tau$) satisfies $\tau$.

For the same reason, there are no truth assignments "falsifying" $\emptyset$; so, $P(\emptyset)=1$.